# mysql select query with php foreach

Tags: php, zend-framework, select, foreach

I am trying to write a function where I will get the id's from a table and then I want to have the all the id's in the array so that these id's used in another function to be processed. 
I wrote the below but it's not array method and also it's printing the id's twice. I searched online and they all suggest to use mysql_fetch_assoc and remove for each..but in my case I am using the zend adapter fetchAll to get the output. Please let me know how I can get the id's in the array and also only once so that I can pass this array and each id is processed one by one..right now with what I have is just stopping after the first one is processed. Thanks.

```
function getID()
  {
    $sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE ready = "1" ';
    $idList = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
    if(!empty($idList)) {
        foreach($idList as $value) {
            echo $value['user_id']."\n";
        }
    }
   }


Output 
201
223
231
334
201
223
231
334
```

Comment: Regarding the duplication, are you absolutely certain that the function isn't being called twice? That code really should only display them once.

Another remote possibility is that the users are really twice in the database although that wouldn't make much sense if 'user_id' is the primary key.

Comment: hi, thanks, i had called it in other place but i thought calling that will give the id's that i can process.., i removed it now and again tested the function, now it shows only once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
function getIDs() {
  $result = array();
  $sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE ready = "1" ';
  $idList = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
  if(!empty($idList)) {
    foreach($idList as $value) {
      echo $value['user_id']."\n";
      array_push(result, $value['user_id']);
    }
  }
  // $result = array_unique($result);
  return $result;
}
```

You will then get the array by:

```
$bunch_of_ids = getIDs();
```

You should figure out why they are being duplicated, but in case you can't, you can make the array content unique with:

```
$result = array_unique($result);
```

Put that right before `return $result;` inside the function. I've commented it in the function above because would be much better to find out why it's being duplicated in the first place. As I noted in a comment to your question, please make sure that the function isn't being called twice. Also check the database for duplicate entries (although that shouldn't be possible if 'user_id' is a primary key).

(Please also note that I renamed the function to getIDs() because it makes no sense to have a getID() function returning multiple values. :) )

Comment: when i say echo $result, it shows "array"..i removed the call for the function in other places and just testing it alone. anything wrong i am doing?

Comment: how do i call this?$bunch_of_ids = getIDs(); in the place where I want to pass the id's as an array?

Comment: It's normal that you can't echo the array because it's an array. If you want to show the content, try "print_r($result)". That should show you the content.

I'm not sure I understand the second question... you just use getIDs() where you want it. Whether it's called $bunch_of_ids or anything else doesn't matter. I don't know your code where you want to use getIDs() - I don't even know why you want it. :)

Comment: sorry, i have got one more question..Now, I am trying to do this

getIDs returns 4 records,

So if I do

Function execute()
{
 for($i=0 ; $i<count($this->getIDs()); $i++) {
 $this->updateUsers();
}


I was hoping that it will do this for all the 4 records but I just does it for first record and nothing after that..anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Please close this question (by marking the correct answer) and open a new one if you have more questions. It's much harder to show code and stuff in the comments.

I would need to see the code in the function $this->updateUsers() to give you a good answer, but $this->updateUsers() doesn't take any parameters, so it can't know which users to update.

I'd love to elaborate, but then I need more than the commenting section so please open a new question and send me a message about it. :)

Comment: @ Helgi Hrafn Gunnarsson - i have a new qustion here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486911/php-for-loop-with-try-catch

Answer (score 0):

this function is correct, but if you want an array:

```
if(!empty($idList)) {
    foreach($idList as $value) {
        $array[] = $value['user_id'];
    }
```

and if `'user_id'` really are repeated:

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks correct to  me, are you sure you are not calling it twice to explain the double output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 function getID(){
 $get = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE ready = '1'", $yhteys);

  for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($get); $i++) {
  $id = mysql_result($get, $i, "user_id");
  $userids[] = $id;
  }
 return $userids;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` is called on evry for loop. it can be slow if mysql_num_rows is big

Answer (score 0):

I think that code is fine. I don't see any mistake there.