# Php for loop with try catch

Tags: php, for-loop

This question is in continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417275/mysql-select-query-with-php-foreach/7417397#7417397) as suggested by one of the user.

I am using the getIDs function as below to process the id's.  CheckValid() will check if the id's is a valid one to be processed, if yes then it will go to the next one updateUsers(). Check valid just checks for a condition and if not it throws an exception. updateUsers() just updates a column if it passes checkValid().

Problem – If I get 4 id's as output from getIDs(), and with the execute(), it process 2 for example and if it fails for 2nd id, it doesn't continue for the rest 2 id's ..I want it to continue so I commented out the "throw $e in the catch block".

```
Function execute() { 
 for($i=0 ; $i<count($this->getIDs()); $i++) { 
try {
 $this->checkValid();
 $this->updateUsers(); 
} catch(Exception $e) {
  //throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Help kittens! Don't kill them !

Comment: Aaaand where's the question? Seems like you "solved" it by doing nothing in the `catch` block?

Comment: `throw` will interupt the loop, but suppressing the errors may not be smart.

Answer (score 1):

have you try a simple continue in the catch block ? didn't test but maybe something like that:

```
Function execute() { 
 for($i=0 ; $i<count($this->getIDs()); $i++) { 
    try {
     $this->checkValid();
     $this->updateUsers(); 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
     //throw $e;
     continue; // if not working try a continue 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using exceptions as booleans, I'd suggest avoiding that, as it gets confusing quickly, unless you really need the contents of the exception.  See if this makes any sense for your use case (I'll grant, it may not).

```
// returns true if valid, false otherwise
function checkValid(){
    try {
        // do your validation
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // optional: save the exception in case we want to know about it
        $this->last_error = $e;
        return false;
    }
}

function execute() { 
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($this->getIDs()); $i++) { 
        if($this->checkValid()){
            $this->updateUsers();
        }
        // if you want to do something with an error, simply add an else clause
        // and handle $this->last_error
    }
}
```

Also, I obviously don't know your code or what exactly you're doing, but looping `n` times and calling `checkValid()` and `updateUsers()` without parameters seems like very poor practice.  Much better to, for instance, loop over the list of IDs and check each ID and user in turn, something like this:

```
foreach($this->getIDs() as $id){
    if($this->checkValid($id)){
        $this->updateUser($id);
    } else {
        // an advantage of this is now we can know exactly which ID failed,
        // because we have the $id variable
    }
}
```